# What is the proper way to override a php function / file containted in the includes / abstracts folder when using woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What is the proper way to override a php file in the includes folder when using woocommerce?

As an example of one of the many things I want to change:
"I think sale prices being wrapped in `<del></del>` is silly(`<span> or <div>` would be better for what i want), and I want to change the layout anyways so I want to alter the code

```
/**
 * Functions for getting parts of a price, in html, used by get_price_html.
 *
 * @param  mixed $from String or float to wrap with 'from' text
 * @param  mixed $to String or float to wrap with 'to' text
 * @return string
 */
public function get_price_html_from_to( $from, $to ) {
    return '<del>' . ( ( is_numeric( $from ) ) ? wc_price( $from ) : $from ) . '</del> <ins>' . ( ( is_numeric( $to ) ) ? wc_price( $to ) : $to ) . '</ins>';
}
```

in file

```
plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php
```

I could just alter it in this file, but I know that is the incorrect way of doing it, and that it would get overwritten by the next woo update also.

***So what is the CORRECT way to alter this code?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the price is greater than 0, you can change the value of the price html via the `woocommerce_sale_price_html` filter. Or if the price is 0, you can target the `woocommerce_free_sale_price_html` filter. See the `get_price_html()` method in the `WC_Product` abstract.

Here's the relevant bit if the price is greater than 0:

```
if ( $this->is_on_sale() && $this->get_regular_price() ) {

    $price .= $this->get_price_html_from_to( $display_regular_price, $display_price ) . $this->get_price_suffix();

    $price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sale_price_html', $price, $this );

}
```

So you could filter the html and instead of using WC's default `get_price_html_from_to` method you could create your own function with your own custom markup, like so:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_price_html', 'so_26002687_sale_price_html', 10, 2);

function so_26002687_sale_price_html( $html, $product ){

    $tax_display_mode      = get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_shop' );
    $display_price  = $tax_display_mode == 'incl' ? $product->get_price_including_tax() : $product->get_price_excluding_tax();
    $display_regular_price = $tax_display_mode == 'incl' ? $product->get_price_including_tax( 1, $product->get_regular_price() ) : $product->get_price_excluding_tax( 1, $product->get_regular_price() );

    $html = so_26002687_get_price_html_from_to( $display_regular_price, $display_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix();

    return $html;

}

function so_26002687_get_price_html_from_to( $from, $to ) {
    return '<span class="from">' . ( ( is_numeric( $from ) ) ? wc_price( $from ) : $from ) . '</span> <span class="to">' . ( ( is_numeric( $to ) ) ? wc_price( $to ) : $to ) . '</span>';
}
```

Then I'd repeat the process for `woocommerce_free_sale_price_html`.

Comment: Got an error "Using $this when not in object context in" What class am I supposed to call for this to work right?

Comment: Sorry. Too much cutting and pasting, not enough editing. The beauty of this is that you don't call or modify any classes. You drop this into your theme's functions.php.

Comment: Ah yes, thats what I was attempting to do originally. Thank you!

Comment: Somehow variable products use get_price_html_from_to but don't go through woocommerce_sale_price_html so they remain un-formatted by this change...  I've tried fiddling with this code in several ways but nothing short of going into abstract-wc-product.php and editing it there seems to work...

Comment: There's a `woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html` filter. Look in the `WC_Product_Variable` class.

Comment: I'll give this a try, and report back. Thanks for the help! (You are everywhere on woocommerce, I just finished reading through several troubleshooting forums from a year ago where you were answering them as well, lol)

Comment: What can I say, I like WooCommerce. I sometimes will see interesting questions here (though a lot are 'please do my work for free') and can use the resulting snippets on my blog. And it just keeps me sharp.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create your own file, and include/require it AFTER you include the original one from woocommerce.
In your file you **redefine** the functions you need to by doing:

```
bool runkit_function_redefine ( string $funcname , string $arglist , string $code );
```

It's your best bet I think, allthough it's a bit obscure.

`$funcname` is the name of the function you want to redefine.

`$arglist` is the new argument list (in `string` format!).

`$code`is the new code (again, in `string` format).

Hope it helps.

Further info: [Redefine PHP manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php)

Comment: Generally speaking, I would not recommend using runkit on a production website.

Comment: Sure, I did say it was a bit obscure :D. But don't mind my answer, yours is the right one. I'm just too braindead to think right now. Dunno how I missed the derivation of the class...

Answer (score 0):

Make your own class that implements the `WC_Product` 'abstract' class, and make sure your products are registered as that type, so that the `WC_Product_Factory` gives you back instances of that class, instead of `WC_Product`; e.g.

```
class WC_Product_Your_Type extends WC_Product {
  public function get_price_html_from_to( $from, $to ) {
    return '<span>' . ( ( is_numeric( $from ) ) ? wc_price( $from ) : $from ) . '</span> <div>' . ( ( is_numeric( $to ) ) ? wc_price( $to ) : $to ) . '</div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried using `class WC_Product_Simple` and `WC_Product_Variable` Woo did not like this. Related products on the archive/catalog page are stripped of all the ajax add_to_cart buttons, and replaced with Read_Me buttons that route to the product page.

AND on the product page, the add_to_cart buttons are gone.

Comment: But it did apply the changes to the price listing.